# .net framework mainstream support

Tags: .net

What is the date of end of support for Microsoft Framework  4.6.1 and 4.6.2?

here  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=framework%20.net i found:

> .NET Framework is a component of the Windows OS. Components receive
>   the same support as their parent product or platform.For more
>   information, please visit the .NET Framework Lifecycle FAQ.

But i did not understand what is the parent OS for this framework.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: If I stand correct, that's the Windows version you are using. If you are using Windows 10, the support for .NET 4.5.2+ on Windows 10 will be the same than the OS

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17455/lifecycle-faq-net-framework, last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [.NET Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Release_history) article on Wikipedia has this information:

> 4.6.1 Windows 10 v1511
>   4.6.2 Windows 10 v1607 *and* Server 2016